# in griffon can I 'configure' a view using an external config file ?

Tags: groovy, griffon

In a griffon view I have some code which constructs a panel based on a model parameter .. So I have  ..

```
if (model.stillageType.equals("SNP3")){
  // build a panel  ..  
}

if (model.stillageType.equals("SNP6")){
  // build a different panel ..  
}
```

I'm currently trying to set the model from the mvcGroupInit via a local config file - I read the file and set the model - but my view appears to be already constructed at this time and nothing is displayed. Once set the value wont change - it's not a dynamic property. I just want to be able to load multiple versions on different PC's each showing a different design panel ..  I can get round it by hardcoding each distribution but i'd really like to load it from a config file .. In my mvcGroupInit routine i have  ..

```
model.stillageType =
         connector.properties.get('stillageType')
```

which will load the model BUT I think the view has already been constructed and it isn't being applied .. Is there anyway I can do this  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this Griffon 1.5 or Griffon 2.0? In Griffon 1.5 you can initialize the model by either providing a constructor or overriding `mvcGroupInit()`; making sure that the `model` member is defined before the `view` in `Config.groovy`. In Griffon 2.0 you may additionally annotate a method with `@PostConstruct`, which will be invoked after the constructor and before the `mvcGroupInit()` method.
Again, makig sure that `model` is defined before `view` (the default) will assure that `model.mvcGroupInit()` is called before the `view` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Griffon 1.5 .. I changed the Config.groovy file for this mvcGroup to create model,controller,view rather than model,view,controller. I'm assuming that this allowed the mvcGroupInit routine to initialize my model correctly BEFORE the view was built - allowing the view to pick up the modified version of my model .. Works fine now ..